# Unable to install KVM for vNext

Tags: cmd, kvm, asp.net-core

As described here: [KVM Install Instructions](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/master/README.md),
 I am trying to install KVM , as it is the 1st step for getting started with and  creating vNext applications.L

I am running the following command on my command prompt:

[image: Command installing KRE]

but i am unable to install KVM any way ...
how can i install KVM?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @DavidPostill i m using windows 7

Comment: What is the output of `echo %path%`? It should be something like `C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;`

Answer (score 0):

On Win7 and Win2008 R2 you have to install Powershell 4
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855

Comment: Can you please run this in powershell and share the output `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`?

Comment: I am unable to install WFM 4.0 , I am going to create a new Post for this problem .. kindly help me there ....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927544/unable-to-install-wmf-4-0-for-window-7-sp1