# Unable to install WMF 4.0 for Window 7 SP1

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to install Windows update for Installing Windows PowerShell 4.0.
The Update is : Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg.msu at [This Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855)

Following are my system Specifications:

[image]

I already have prerequisites to install WMF 4.0 which are SP1 and .NET 4.5.

I get a simple plain error with no details that update can not be installed.

[image]

what can i do to install this particular update?

Just in case anyone want to know, I need to install this update to Install KVM required for building VNext Apps.

Comment: There should be a more detailed error in the Windows log.  There are [reports](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2013/10/29/wmf-4-0-known-issue-partial-installation-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx) that incomplete installations can cause issues. There are also [reports](http://serverfault.com/questions/591904/unable-to-install-powershell-4) that you must have .NET 4.5 exactly (i.e., 4.5.1 will not work) but it's not clear if this report isn't just due to an incomplete installation.

Comment: @BaconBits I do have 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.3 versions of .NET Framework

Comment: @BaconBits also, u can see from Specs, i do have SP 1 of windows 7 .
Do i have to reinstall SP1?

Comment: I wouldn't think a reinstall of SP1 would be necessary, no.  SP1 predates WMF 4.0.  I would probably start by just trying to do a full reinstall of .Net 4.5.3.  If that didn't work, then I'd remove everything back to .NET 4.5, then install 4.5, then WMF 4.0.  If that works, you should be able to install .NET 4.5.3.

Comment: Wait, 4.5.3 is the 4.6 Preview.  Yeah, I'd bet that might be causing problems.

Comment: @BaconBits So u say i should Uninstall all versions of .NET Except 4.5,
and what if Windows 7 is not genuine ?

Comment: Can't help you there.